# I Made a html drop down bar but it goes behind everything

Tags: html, hover

hey i am doing html at the moment and at the top i have a drop down bar but under it i have a image and text so when the bar drops down it goes under the image and text.

dose anyone know a code that will make it hover over the image and text?

Comment: your code works fine, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spj7E/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index:999` to your `ul` CSS. The `999` can be any value that is higher than everything else on the page.

Comment: sorry mate where should i add this? what part of the css?

Comment: @Brendan5544 `ul { list-style: none; }` => `ul { list-style: none; z-index: 999 }`

Comment: thank you so much mate it worked but can you explain what you just told me to do did? what is the z-index?

Comment: `z-index` allows you to specify which overlapping element is visible. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index for a longer explanation. (Also, please select a "Best Answer" for the sake of future users.)

Comment: The `z-index` is how far 'forward' the element is. If two or more elements overlap, they are rendered with the lower numbered indexes behind the higher ones. All elements have it set implicitly to `0`. I normally avoid using numbers like 999, preferring to set them to 1, 2, 3 and so on. 999 is just a simpler way of saying put this on top of everything else.

Comment: @CarlSmith There's more to the default value than `0`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Answer (score 0):

Choose and assign different z-index to each.

A number like 9999 could then be used as the "absolute top ever value", which would be visually recognizable because of the different numbering convention.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS :**

```
li:hover > ul { display: block; z-index:999; }
```

Add this to your code index value 999 is greater then all the index value on the page.